# How To Fix Error In Laravel. 'Trying To get property country of non object'

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the Exception Code Code
In the Framework/views/profile_settings.blade.php

When my users visit their profile setting the stack trace errors always come up with the exception. Please help me out. Thanks

```
$('select[name=country]').val('<?php echo e($user->address->country); ?>');
```

Comment: I tried change .val to value but I still get same errors

Comment: Add change trigger `$('select[name=country]').val('<?php echo e($user->address->country); ?>')->change();` like this `$('select[name=country]').val('Canada')->change();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

### Null Safe Operator

If you are using less version of php 8. You can write these type of code

```
$country = null;
    if ($user !== null) {
            if ($user->address !== null) {
                $country = $user->address->country;
            }
        }
```

PHP 8 allows you to write this.

```
$country = $user?->address?->country;
```

It will work like these

[Helpfull Link](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator)

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of posting links to external ressources

Comment: Explanation Done @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1):

`$user->address` is probably returning null. Try something like:

```
{{ $user->address->country ?? '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an address in my db but in json format, and some times comes without country.

the way I fixed this was making new property to handle this:

```
 public function getAddressAsStringAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->address == null) return null;
        if (is_object($this->address) && property_exists($this->address, 'country'))
            return $this->address->country;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

now you can use this new property like:

```
$('select[name=country]').val('<?php echo e($user->addressAsString); ?>');
```